# How to toggle font-awesome icons inside bootstrap with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a bootstrap accordion in my template and a font awesome fa fa-angle-double-right that. How do I toggle this on expand and collapse?
Change to `fa fa-angle-double-down` on expand and change to `fa fa-angle-double-right` on hide

This is my template:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'partials/form_field.html' with field=form.title %}
    {% include 'partials/form_field.html' with field=form.body %}
    {% include 'partials/form_field.html' with field=form.score %}

 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#respond"aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="respond">
          Click to respond to this review <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="respond" class="panel-collapse collapse {% if review.responder_name and review.response %}in{%endif %}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="response">
      <div class="panel-body">
          {% include 'partials/form_field.html' with field=form.responder_name %}
          {% include 'partials/form_field.html' with field=form.response %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a href="{% url 'backend_reviews' %}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Review" />
 <a href="{% url 'backend_reviews_delete' review.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Delete Review</a>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var toggled = false;
    $('a[role="button"]').click(function(){
        if(toggled == false){
           $(this).find('span').addClass('fa fa-angle-double-down').removeClass('fa fa-angle-double-right');
           toggled = true;
        }else{
           $(this).find('span').addClass('fa fa-angle-double-right').removeClass('fa fa-angle-double-down');
           toggled  = false;
        }
    });
```

Another way can be...

```
$('a[role="button"]').click(function(){
$(this).find('span').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-down fa-angle-double-right');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain voting down?

Comment: I did not vote down.
And this just appends 'fa fa-angle-double-down' to the class, making the icon unable to render

Comment: Try the edited answer and let me know if that solves it.

Comment: It doesn't. It works like this: Hidden and on click makes icon unable to render and expands, (should've changed to double-down)
Click again hides the section, and now the icon has changed to double down (It should've changed to double right)

Comment: Did you try the toggleClass one?

Comment: Your answer works, had to make a minor change to my code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what that minor change was to your code, DeA, which led you to accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Here we go:

```
$(".fa-angle-double-right").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('class', 'fa fa-angle-double-down');
});
```

> Edit for changed question:

HTML

```
<span id="angle" class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span>
```

Javascript with JQuery

```
$("#angle").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class') == "fa fa-angle-double-right"){
        $(this).attr('class', 'fa fa-angle-double-down');
    }
    else{
        $(this).attr('class', 'fa fa-angle-double-right');    
    }   
});
```

Comment: Yes, but this only works once. It won't revert back to double-up when clicked again

Comment: @DeA: Then store and toggle a variable that decides what state you want. What is the problem here exactly? (And please add this requirement to your question; you didn't even mention it)

Comment: You didn't ask for it, anyway if you want, you can give an id to the element and change the class by checking its current class. Hope you will mark my answer ^^

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Sorry about that, I wanted toggle, there we go, I have changed it